# Or inside Case statement

Tags: t-sql

trying to figure out how to incorporate an OR in a case statement in T-SQL

I'm essentially checking for 2 things, and if either one is true, just look at them as 0 for the count.

```
COUNT(Case When (car[Weight] IS null) then 0 else car.CarKey 
           OR When (car.BinNumber is null) then 0 else car.CarKey 
      End) as Carkey
```

also tried this but syntax is wrong

```
COUNT(Case When (car[Weight] IS null) then 0 
         else When (car.BinNumber is null) then 0 
         else car.CarKey 
      End) as Carkey
```

Comment: For future reference, case statements don't split that way.  CASE WHEN (...) THEN ... WHEN (...) THEN ... ELSE ... END;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `OR` this way:

```
COUNT(Case 
        When (car.[Weight] IS null) or (car.BinNumber is null)
        then 0 
        else car.CarKey End) as Carkey
```

Comment: But, this will count the 0's.  Is that what OP wants?

Perhaps he wants SUM(CASE...THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS CarKey

Comment: @GilM supposedly, yes that is what they want.  That would be a question for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your second attempt, just remove one `else`

```
COUNT(Case When (car[Weight] IS null) then 0 
     When (car.BinNumber is null) then 0 
     else car.CarKey 
  End) as Carkey
```

Note: If you want to count the items without null values, that won't do it. A zero value is still a value, so it will also be counted. Use `null` for items that you don't want to count:

```
COUNT(Case When (car[Weight] IS null) then null 
     When (car.BinNumber is null) then null 
     else car.CarKey 
  End) as Carkey
```

Or use `sum` instead:

```
SUM(Case When (car[Weight] IS null) then 0 
     When (car.BinNumber is null) then 0 
     else 1
  End) as Carkey
```